# Equation with logarithms and absolute values

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

I have this equation and I want to solve it for $x<0$.
$$\frac{\ln|x|}{|x|}=\frac{\ln|x|}{x}$$
According to WolframAlpha, the solution is $x=-1$ but I don't know how to get that.

My approach:
$$\frac{\ln|x|}{|x|}=\frac{\ln|x|}{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{|x|}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$|x|=x$$
$$-x=x$$
$$2x=0$$
$$x=0$$
which is apparently wrong. Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: Hint, the given equation may be satisfied as well when $\ln|x|=0$

Comment: Under "My approach", the 3rd equation is not equivalent to the 4th equation. Also, the transition from the 2nd to the 3rd equation has the implicit condition that $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @Mann - I can't believe I didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

if $x\neq -1$,

$$\frac{\ln|x|}{x}=\frac{\ln|x|}{|x|}\implies \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{|x|}$$

Comment: because if $x=-1$ then $\ln|x|=0$, and you can't divide by $0$ ! But notice that $x=-1$ is also a solution, so you have to add it at the set of the solutions at the end ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that just before you answered. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome :-)